# Deleting random letters from Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of content featuring URL shortcodes that share the same domain, but always end in a random string of 7 alphanumeric characters.

Example: http://www.randomstrin.gs/1nfGi8X

I want to delete hundreds of them at once. Any regex formula I find and use does not end at the 7th character and is in fact removing additional content after the domain in the content. I'm stuck!

Thanks so much for any and all advice.

Comment: Please add an example data(5-10 url) you are working with and also show the regex you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @JackBrown! Thank you so much for replying. The regex I've used is this:
 `(\http://randomstrin.gs).*`

Comment: Hey Jack, for example, if I have a piece of content that is `http://randomstrin.gs/1nfGi8x #IoT`, the regex above `(\http://randomstring.gs).*` will remove the #IoT as well, but end there. I want it to just end right after the random characters.

Comment: Fixed! For anyone wondering, I used these two find and replaces: `http://randomstrin\.gs/(\S+) ` and `http://randomstrin\.gs/(\S+)`. The second is missing a blank space after, which was added for the first regex because it was deleting more than just the string I was isolating.

Comment: Add as answer below and you can accept your own tanswer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! For anyone wondering, I used these two find and replaces: `http://randomstrin\.gs/(\S+)` and `http://randomstrin\.gs/(\S+)`. The second is missing a blank space after, which was added for the first regex because it was deleting more than just the string I was isolating. –